# Cpu usage information through ADB

Tags: android, linux, performance, adb

I am trying to measure the cpu usage of an Android application through adb. I am approaching this by doing the following commands:

```
dumpsys cpuinfo packagename

adb shell top | grep packagename
```

I get different CPU usage stats from each one of these commands. What exactly is the difference between them and which would be more reliable if I am looking to create a graph of the cpu utilization of the application wrt the input provided.

Comment: see same thing with question on stackoverflow ->What's Android ADB shell 'dumpsys' tool and it's benefits?

Comment: That post only mentions a list of all the dumpsys commands